# Joining 2 videos using ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg

My command is:

```
ffmpeg -y -i 2.mp4 -i 2.mp4 -filter_complex '[0:0] [0:1] [1:0] [1:1] concat=n=2:v=1:a=1 [v] [a]' -map '[v]' -map '[a]' output.mp4
```

the result is:

```
ffmpeg version N-50911-g9efcfbe Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers built on Mar 13 2013 21:26:48 with gcc 4.7.2 (GCC) configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnu tls --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore -amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex - -enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libxa vs --enable-libxvid --enable-zlib libavutil 52. 19.100 / 52. 19.100 libavcodec 55. 0.100 / 55. 0.100 libavformat 55. 0.100 / 55. 0.100 libavdevice 54. 4.100 / 54. 4.100 libavfilter 3. 45.103 / 3. 45.103 libswscale 2. 2.100 / 2. 2.100 libswresample 0. 17.102 / 0. 17.102 libpostproc 52. 2.100 / 52. 2.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '2.mp4': Metadata: major_brand : isom minor_version : 512 compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41 date : 2015-07-02T14:59:07.00754+03:00 encoder : Lavf55.0.100 Duration: 00:00:07.03, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 24 kb/s
Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High 4:4:4 Predictive) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv444p, 500x281, 21 kb/s, 29.74 fps, 29.74 tbr, 11896 tbn, 59.48 tbc Metadata: handler_name : VideoHandler
Input #1, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '2.mp4': Metadata: major_brand : isom minor_version : 512 compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41 date : 2015-07-02T14:59:07.00754+03:00 encoder : Lavf55.0.100 Duration: 00:00:07.03, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 24 kb/s
Stream #1:0(und): Video: h264 (High 4:4:4 Predictive) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv444p, 500x281, 21 kb/s, 29.74 fps, 29.74 tbr, 11896 tbn, 59.48 tbc Metadata: handler_name : VideoHandler
[AVFilterGraph @ 020ae7c0] No such filter: '[0:0]' Error configuring filters.
```

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! I would recommend reading [How do I ask a good question](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) if you haven't already. Is still unclear what you are trying to achieve- is it 2 videos joined one after the other, or two show two simultaneously? Have you read https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate ?

Comment: hi,its 2 videos one after the other.i have read everything...

Comment: Please show the **complete** console output from your command.

Answer (score 0):

Your two inputs seem to be the same file (2.mp4); so you can do a bitstream copy as mentioned on the documentation page on [Concatenating videos](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate) as the codec parameters will match:

file concat.txt:

```
file '/full/path/to/2.mp4'
file '/full/path/to/2.mp4'
```

and then use the command:

```
$ ffmpeg  -f concat -i concat.txt -c copy out.mp4
```

However, you will have to **upgrade to a newer version of ffmpeg**, as this option was only added after v1.1.

The method you are trying to use (listed under ['concatenation of files with different codecs'](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate#differentcodec)) notes that:

> The concat filter is **available in recent versions of ffmpeg**.

*(emphasis mine)*

So **you will need to upgrade** if you wish to use this on files with different codecs.

Your command works for me as-is with other video files substituted. If you absolutely cannot upgrade ffmpeg at all, read the [concat protocol section of the documentation](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate#protocol) for options there:

> If you have MP4 files, these could be losslessly concatenated by first transcoding them to mpeg transport streams. With h.264 video and AAC audio, the following can be used:
>
> ```
> ffmpeg -i input1.mp4 -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts intermediate1.ts
> ffmpeg -i input2.mp4 -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts intermediate2.ts
> ffmpeg -i "concat:intermediate1.ts|intermediate2.ts" -c copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc output.mp4
> ```

I include this for completeness, but I haven't used this method myself, unlike the others. You can also use the [external script](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate#extscript) that they note if you have files with different codecs.

Comment: I have edited my answer to address this, but it comes down to upgrading ffmpeg or using an external script to try to match the parameters, as per the [Concatenate docs](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate)